# Observe the HTTP request made on a page and post it to a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, httprequest

I have a web page that contains a SWF object(external) that loads up random content by making HTTP requests to its server. Is there any way I can implement a sort of observer for the page that stores all the HTTP request that were made once the page was loaded.

I'll appreciate any help on the topic, I just need a point to start on.. I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests from a Flash file occur on the client, so if the request goes off to a different server (not yours) your server won't even know that it's occurred. You'd need to install something on the client to track it.

Comment: I was thinking of writing a js script that monitors the HTTP requests made (since it runs on the client side ) and then post it to a php script using ajax

Comment: If you have access to the Flash source then you could track it there. If you don't have access then I doubt you'd be able to track it via JS. I don't know enough about Flash though to know how much access JS has.